# Scrolling `<ul>` animation

Tags: css

I'm trying to recreate an AdMob banner, where I have a title on one line and below it another line with continuously scrolling content - 1 line for description, 1 line for link etc...

So for this second line I created a wrapping div and inside it a `<ul>` list, whith `<li>` for every line:

```
<div class="details-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><p>Description LINE 1111</p></li>
        <li><p>Description LINE 2222</p></li>
        <li><p>Description LINE 1111</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The last line is similar to first cause I thought that since it has to make continuous scroll it should scroll up the third line and sort of make a jump to the first, so the move appears to be seamless. I styled everything and created the animation:

```
.details-wrapper, ul, li {height:22px; clear:both; overflow:hidden; position:relative;}
ul {position: absolute; -webkit-animation: mover 6s infinite linear forwards; overflow:visible; width: 100%;}
ul, li{margin:0;}
li {clear:both; list-style-type:none; display:table; vertical-align:middle; padding-left:14px; height:100%; width:100%;}
li p {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
li:first-child p, li:nth-child(2) p, li:nth-child(3) p {color:#46d200; font-size: 12px; text-overflow: ellipsis; -webkit-line-clamp: 1; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; display: -webkit-box; overflow:hidden; position: absolute; top: 50%; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);}
.icon-wrapper {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    float: right;
    margin: 3px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mover {
    0%{top:0;}
    25%{top:0;}
    30%{top:-22px;}
    75%{top:-22px;}
    80%{top:-44px;}
}
```

When I test it in desktop Chrome - everything works fine. But once I test it in mobile Webkit based browser - it scrolls back from the last line to first, without making the jump.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p1ywjjfj/)

Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved with the following animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes mover {
    0%{top:0;}
    20%{top:0;}
    30%{top:-22px;}
    70%{top:-22px;}
    80%{top:-44px;}
    100%{top:-44px;}
}
```